# logging to pappertrailapp using NLog in asp.net core (1.0.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog, syslog

i have issues with logging to pappertailapp from asp.net core(1.0.1) 
i have downloaded and used [this NLog solution](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging)

by tutorial all works perfectly it saving logs to local folder and i can see logs.

but by tutorial of [pappertrailapp - NLog](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/nlog-net-logging/)  
i change my nlog.config target paths with this line:

```xml
<target name="syslog" type="Syslog" 
        syslogserver="logs.papertrailapp.com" port="myport" facility="Local7"/>
```

> syslogserver and port take from my pappertrailapp account.

and there is no logs from my local machine and staging server (all the ips(my local and server) are configured in pappertrailapp and all MVC  .NET 4 are works but not new ASP.NET Core apps.)

thanks!

Comment: What is your platform? Net core (app) or net46?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [NLog.Targets.Syslog is not yet compatible with Core projects](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/80). You can try taking a look at the config instructions on the NLog github [specifically for Core projects](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki), but I don't see any options as of yet that will support Papertrail.

It does seem like [log4net is ready to support Core + Papertrail](https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/), if switching logging libraries is a reasonable option for you.